# After Update my Android Studio (Dolphin | 2021.3.1), XML Layout Preview Can't showing

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

**Version Information:**

Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1

Build #AI-213.7172.25.2113.9014738, built on September 1, 2022

Runtime version: 11.0.13+0-b1751.21-8125866 amd64

Comment: Close the android studio then remove .idea file then reopen android studio

Answer (score 2):

For anyone is facing this issue, i solved it by update gradle version and buildtool, because new android studio seem not work with older version which our project is using.

update `buildToolVersion`  to `7.3.0` in buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/Dependencies.kt

```
object BuildPlugins {
    object Versions {
        const val buildToolVersion = "7.3.0" //lower version seem not work
```

and change to `7.4` in gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-bin.zip
```

hope this can help

Comment: After upgrade buildToolVersion, It's working. 
Thank you so much dear.

Comment: still not working with third party lib views like Lottie and WebViews

Answer (score 1):

Downgrard your project into `build.gradle [app level]` Change your targetSdk and compileSdk `33` to `32`, and downgrade your library...

Change minSdk atleast `21`

```
android{

    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
       minSdk 21
       targetSdk 32
       ...
    }
...
}
```

And

Use this versions of librarys ...

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
```

Comment: Thank you dear. I had did this, but same as previous. But After updating Build Tool version, It's working.

Comment: @HridoyKrisnaDas what Build Tool version are you using?

Comment: On build.gradle:

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
        //Others
}

and on gradle-wrapper.properties:

distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip